# Accessing Swf flash form elements from JS

Tags: javascript, actionscript

Is there a way that i can controll my(!) swf form fields?
I want to get and set the data from JS.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up `ExternalInterface` in the ActionScript reference.